# How to make `\cref` after expansion stand at the same group of surrounding text?

Tags: cleveref, grouping

I would like to make `\cref` after expansion stand at the same group of surrounding text.

With `\crefname{figure}{图}{图}`, I need to use `如\cref{...} 所示` to make typesetting correct, if the counter of `figure` environment is not set to Chinese numbers.
Note that there is *no whitespace* before `\cref` whereas there is *one* after.
This make `\cref{...}` bear no resemblance to Chinese or English.
Therefore the syntax becomes more complex—there are three languages: Chinese, English, a virtual language starting with Chinese but ending with English.
Besides, the virtual language is dependent on the format of counter.
By making the expansion of `\cref` stand at the same group of surrounding text, the third one is eliminated, and there is neither behavioral nor syntactic change in English-only scenario, since `\cref` is semantically treated like an ordinary English word in the text and always surrounded by spaces.

Bearing in mind that grouping is desired sometimes (e.g., when one uses `\crefname{figure}{\bfseries FIG.}{\bfseries Fig.}`), I prefer (if possible) a switch.

I guess this request is much like making the expansion of `\textbf{...}` stand at the same group of surrounding text.

Could this be achieved?

**EDIT**: With XeLaTeX, the following code gives the output:

[image: output]

MWE:

```latex
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}% Note: some Chinese fonts are needed
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \crefname{figure}{图}{图}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\caption{test}
\label{eq:test}
\end{figure}

中文 字符 之间 不 需要 空格。% direct translation of each piece: Chinese, character(s), between, not, need, whitespace(s). Combination: There is no need to place whitespaces between Chinese characters.

前后\par % case 1
前 后\par% case 2
前\cref{eq:test}后 --- \verb|\cref|\par  % case 3
前 \cref{eq:test} 后 --- \verb|\cref|\par% case 4. I would like to make case 4 behave like case 3.
前\ref{eq:test}后 --- \verb|\ref|\par  % case 5
前 \ref{eq:test} 后 --- \verb|\ref|\par% case 6. I would like to make case 6 behave like case 5.

Note the very different behaviour of \verb|\ref| and \verb|\cref|.

one \textbf{two} three\par
one\textbf{two}three\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal example document to your question? Preferably also showing what the current output is and how you want the output to be given the input. This will make it easier for potential answerers to start trying out possible solutions.

Comment: As a workaround suggestion: would it be useful to redefine the `\cref` command (or possibly introduce a secondary command for this) that always prints a hard space (`\ `) after the figure name? Or define `\crefname` as `图\ `?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks. But it is not usefull for Chinese since there is no need to group Chinese characters—thus whitespaces are usually not used in Chinese-only text.

Answer (score 5):

You can suppress the space by redefining the format commands. If you want it also for normal \ref, the easiest is to define your own command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}% Note: some Chinese fonts are needed
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{\unskip 图}{\unskip 图}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3\aftergroup\ignorespaces} 
\newcommand\myref[1]{\unskip\ref{#1}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\caption{test}
\label{eq:test}
\end{figure}

前后\par % case 1
前 后\par% case 2
前\cref{eq:test}后 --- \verb|\cref|\par  % case 3
前 \cref{eq:test}  后 --- \verb|\cref|\par% case 4. I would like to make case 4 behave like case 3.
前\myref{eq:test}后 --- \verb|\ref|\par  % case 5
前 \myref{eq:test} 后 --- \verb|\ref|\par% case 6. I would like to make case 6 behave like case 5.

Note the very different behaviour of \verb|\ref| and \verb|\cref|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution to `\ref`. But for `\cref`, spacing is not correct—the whitespace after the number 1 is absent.

Comment: Yes I quite carefully removed the space because you wrote that you want case 4 to behave like case 3. Undo my definitions if you don't want it.

Comment: My output is different from yours. Which TeX engine is used? I use the XeTeX and TrueType fonts for Chinese.

Comment: I used pdflatex, sorry I didn't see the line in your example and you didn't write in your question that you are using xelatex, remove the `\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3\aftergroup\ignorespaces}` and the other \ignorespaces in this case.

Comment: Apology from me, I should note the use of xetex. On my machine, xetex throws an error—`Undefined control sequence. \cref@figure@name ->\unskip图`

Comment: add a space after \unskip, with xelatex the chinese char is a letter and so is part of the command name.

Comment: Great! By only one command the problem is solved. Many thanks.