# How to define a variant of `\unskip` which does not take effect after specified characters (e.g., punctuation marks)?

Tags: xetex, cleveref, xecjk, chinese

I am using `cleveref` to automate cross references including label names.
Besides, I need to write documents with Chinese and English characters, thus **XeLaTeX** is used.
The document class takes care of spacing between Chinese and English characters.
To use the macro `\cref` from `cleveref` like a English phrase, and make the macro behave correctly when it is defined to begin with a Chinese character, I am using the solution in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569547), i.e.,

```
\crefname{figure}{\unskip 图}{\unskip 图}
```

to customize label names.

However, this solution behaves incorrectly after punctuation marks, because there are compression rules for punctuation marks.

So I would like to define a macro which is similar to `\unskip` but has no effect after specified characters (e.g., punctuation marks).
Is this possible?
Or one should add much more sugar to `\crefname{figure}{...}{...}`?

---

**MWE**

```latex
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontset = founder]{ctex}% Note: some Chinese fonts are needed
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \crefname{figure}{\unskip 图}{\unskip 图}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\caption{test}
\label{eq:test}
\end{figure}

% With XeLaTeX
中 文\par
中文\par
中 English\par
中English\par

前\cref{eq:test}后 --- \verb|\cref|\par  % case 1. correct
前 \cref{eq:test} 后 --- \verb|\cref|\par% case 2. correct
前\ref{eq:test}后 --- \verb|\ref|\par    % case 3. half wrong
前 \ref{eq:test} 后 --- \verb|\ref|\par  % case 4. correct

但是，\cref{eq:test}表明\par    % case 5: wrong
但是， \cref{eq:test} 表明\par  % case 6: wrong
但是，\ref{eq:test}表明\par     % case 7: half wrong
但是， \ref{eq:test} 表明\par   % case 8: correct
但是，图~\ref{eq:test} 表明\par % case 9: wanted

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I do not give you a redefinition or alternative to `\unskip`.  What I do is run the document through a `tokencycle` environment.  If a cat-12 token is found, it sets the flag `\puncttrue` for the moment.  If a `\cref` is found prior to finding either a macro or non-cat-12 token, an additional `\mbox{}` is inserted into the input stream, to prevent any `\unskip` from acting on tokens issued prior to the `\mbox`.

Proviso: the token cycle, because it examines all the tokens in advance before executing them, any catcode changing trickery (notably `verbatim`) must occur outside of the tokencycle, which can be stopped and restarted.

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[fontset = founder]{ctex}% Note: some Chinese fonts are needed
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Microsoft JhengHei UI}

\setCJKfamilyfont{YaHei}{Microsoft YaHei UI}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \crefname{figure}{\unskip 图}{\unskip 图}

\newif\ifpunct
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks{#1}
  \tctestifcatnx,#1{\puncttrue}{\punctfalse}}
\Macrodirective{%
  \ifpunct
    \ifx\cref#1\addcytoks{\mbox{}}\fi
  \fi
  \punctfalse
  \addcytoks{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
\begin{figure}
\centering
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\caption{test}
\label{eq:test}
\end{figure}

% With XeLaTeX
中 文\par
中文\par
中 English\par
中English\par

前\cref{eq:test}后 --- \texttt{\textbackslash cref}\par  % case 1. correct
前 \cref{eq:test} 后 --- \texttt{\textbackslash cref}\par% case 2. correct
前\ref{eq:test}后 --- \texttt{\textbackslash ref}\par    % case 3. half wrong
前 \ref{eq:test} 后 --- \texttt{\textbackslash ref}\par  % case 4. correct

但是，\cref{eq:test}表明\par    % case 5: wrong
但是， \cref{eq:test} 表明\par  % case 6: wrong
但是，\ref{eq:test}表明\par     % case 7: half wrong
但是， \ref{eq:test} 表明\par   % case 8: correct
但是，图~\ref{eq:test} 表明\par % case 9: wanted
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, many thanks. If I am not mistaken, this solution would add little compilation time since it only check the categories of tokens. Am I right?

Comment: @Eli4ph I am not an expert on run-time characteristics, but my experience is `tokcycle` runs very fast.